# Closures in Python Query

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand `Closures` in Python and have come across the following code:

```
def return_func_that_prints_list(z):
    def f():
        print z
    return f

z = [1,2]
g = return_func_that_prints_list(z)
g()

# Output is [1,2,3]
z.append(3)
g()
```

I don't understand the output here:

```
# Why is the Output still [1,2,3]?
z = [1]
g()
```

I don't understand the output here:

```
# Why is the Output still [1,2,3]?
z.append(4)
g()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line:

> ```
> z = [1]
> ```

**rebinds** `z` so that it is no longer pointing to the object contained within the closure. But the closure still has its own copy of the old object, so its behavior does not change.